# last command only shows few days worth of logins

Tags: security, output, last

I often use the`last` command to check my systems for unauthorized logins, this command:

```
last -Fd
```

gives me the logins where I have remote logins showing with ip.

From `man last`:

```
-F     Print full login and logout times and dates.
-d     For non-local logins, Linux stores not only the host name of the remote host but its IP number as well. This option  translates  the  IP
              number back into a hostname.
```

Question:

One of my systems is only showing a few days worth of logins. Why is that? What can I do when `last` only gives me few days?

Here is the output in question:

```
root ~ # last -Fd
user pts/0        111-111-111-111. Wed Oct  8 20:05:51 2014   still logged in                      
user pts/0        host.lan   Mon Oct  6 09:52:01 2014 - Mon Oct  6 09:53:41 2014  (00:01)    
user pts/0        host.lan   Sat Oct  4 10:11:39 2014 - Sat Oct  4 10:12:13 2014  (00:00)    
user pts/0        host.lan   Sat Oct  4 09:31:07 2014 - Sat Oct  4 10:11:00 2014  (00:39)    
user pts/0        host.lan   Sat Oct  4 09:26:04 2014 - Sat Oct  4 09:28:16 2014  (00:02)    

wtmp begins Sat Oct  4 09:26:04 2014
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is likely that `logrotate` has archived the log(s) of interest and opened a new one.  If you have older `wtmp` files, specify one of those, as for example:

```
last -f /var/log/wtmp-20141001
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'last' command reads data from /var/log/wtmp file. If you have logrotate service enabled it probably rotates wtmp file. Check if you have wtmp.1 or wtmp.1.gz file inside of /var/log directory. If you have it (or more similar with next numbers: wtmp.2 wtmp.3, etc) it means wtmp log is rotated. Then you can adjust/disable rotation or use 'last -f wtmp_file' command to check older data.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108490/89057) you can use :

```
$ lastlog -b 0 -t 100
```

To find out the users that have logged into a system in the last 100 days.